# Why does this not make infinite energy?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation

Here's an idea I had for infinite energy: Get into a spaceship, and fly to a star or other large body and get into orbit. Then just harvest your kinetic energy somehow and keep going indefinitely.

My counter this would be that the gravity acts more and more on the "stockpiled" energy as you accumulate more of it, and the energy it would take to nudge yourself back into orbit would equalize, but I don't really know.

Comment: Are you primarily considering the kinetic energy as the direction of motion of orbit, or the "falling" of gravity that creates an orbit? Also - at what level of orbit are you considering? Low-Earth orbiting objects don't orbit for an incredibly long time.

Comment: That's not infinite energy, just potential energy.   As the potential energy is harvested, well, the ship would get closer and closer to the star, until . . . the wax melts and the feathers fall off.  :-)   Never mind that it's rather difficult for an object in orbit to harvest it's own potential energy.     But a solar panel would work.  That's probobly easier.

Comment: It's the "keep going indefinitely and wave some enormous foam hand" that usually doesn't work.

Comment: I rather like the "harvest your kinetic energy", which means basically "slow yourself down somehow".  Next thing you know, you're falling head-first into a big yellow ball of burning gas (yes, I know that stars aren't technically yellow or burning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then just harvest your kinetic energy somehow and keep going indefinitely.

But this doesn't result in infinite energy. All "harvesting" of kinetic energy is based on lowering the difference in linear speed or angular velocity between two bodies. Clearly, your starting velocity relative to the planet limits the total kinetic energy you could harvest (without drawing from other sources of mechanical energy, such as gravitational potential energy (which are also finite, by the way)).

By limiting yourself to a sufficiently slow rate of energy extraction, you can make a finite starting energy last an arbitrarily long time, so performing the quoted statement wouldn't violate the laws of physics.